# CodeDeploy overwrites Directories it's not supposed to touch

Tags: continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I run two versions of the same service (beta and prod) on the same EC2 box.
Each service consists of two processes running in two separate directories A, B.
so, in the /var/myproject/ directory, I have four folders
A
A.beta
B
B.beta

I'm using CodeDeploy (as part of a Code Pipeline) to deploy these two stages
here is the appspec.yml I have (for the prod stage)

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: DeployFolders/ProcessA
    destination: /var/myproject/A
  - source: DeployFolders/ProcessB
    destination: /var/myproject/B
permissions:
  - object: /var/myproject/A
    mode: 777     
  - object: /var/myproject/B
    mode: 777
```

for the beta stage

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: DeployFolders/ProcessA
    destination: /var/myproject/A.beta
  - source: DeployFolders/ProcessB
    destination: /var/myproject/B.beta
permissions:
  - object: /var/myproject/A.beta
    mode: 777     
  - object: /var/myproject/B.beta
    mode: 777
```

The Prod stage runs after the beta stage *and deletes the beta deployment folders (A.beta and B.beta)*
Next deployment, as I deploy the beta stage first, it *deletes the prod deployment folders (A and B)* that had been created before.

I understand that CodeDeploy must and will overwrite the *destination* folders, but in this case, it is deleting sibling folders.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using same deployment-group for this, if you have different appspec.yml files use different deployment-groups in same application and then it will work.

Comment: How are your deployment groups and applications set up?

Comment: I also wonder if the period in the name could be a problem. Might be worth swapping out with an _ to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I ended up using different deployment-groups as @mRo suggested